# PHP / Zend - Sequence data from POST method

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a form that sends an amount of data received by the `POST` method, above the limit set in `php.ini`. This data is received in a PHP array.

I do not want to change the value of `post_max_size` in `php.ini` (already set at 10M).

I thought about a solution by dividing POST data in my form, and retrieve everything in my controller, but I have no idea if this is possible.

Is there a way to bypass this restriction ? (usefull for BIG php array)

If someone has an idea, I will be really grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: I just took the liberty of editing your question to make it more understandable ;)

Comment: Are all your data mandatory ? There are ways to do what you want, but i'm not sure this is a good idea to split your data in a stateful controller

Comment: You could also post it partially with an AJAX, store it temporary in the memory and when all the data is sent, then proceed the data

Comment: @Unex Yes I need all the POST data. I can't find any other solution, I don't want to change php.ini, because the POST data will surely increase in this form.